# VIMEO embed player behave strange if I detect window onblur and pause the video

Tags: javascript, vimeo, vimeo-player

I embed the vimeo player and need to auto pause when window is onblur.

I'm using the current VIEMO SDK API (https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js)

so my code is following

```
var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);
var myWindow = window;

player.on('play', function(data) {
  console.log("Playing...");
  myWindow.focus();
  myWindow.onblur = function() {
    player.pause();
    console.log("You gone...");
  };
});
```

And this work perfectly when user click away the active window (EX: change browser tab, or the browser lost focus)

But the big problem is after start playing the video. When the user click the "pause" button (or just click anywhere wanted to pause) inside the embed player. The video just won't "pause, it seems like it will pause for a very short small period then continue play again!!! After many tries still I can't get this issue out.

I tried to set a small delay to the pause command:

```
setTimeout(function(){ player.pause();}, 300);
```

Which helps a little bit, but still sometime the video will just continue to play itself.

And I also tried to make a outside "Pause" button, then this "button" will behave normally, it can really pause the playing video without any issue. But I really don't want to put a outside button to pause the video, that make the interface sth ugly.

I made an codepen page to reproduce this issue as following
https://codepen.io/kit-leong/pen/PoZWZEj

Can anybody get me some idea about these? Thanks

Comment: I think I finally figure it out what's going on. The issue is that when the user "click" the "pause" button in the iframe, the onblur event will fire instantly. So at that moment in fact the video is paused.So after that moment when the "click" really occur inside the iframe, the video will then "play" (the play/pause button in the video is same) again.

Comment: So I end up adding a little delay to attach the blur event and pause comment. And clear the event after the pause event. It seems everything works now... I made a new codepen page: https://codepen.io/kit-leong/pen/XWXpBZV